# critical error with blossomtheme on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm building the blog using blossomtheme femine pro theme with wordpress.
After installing the theme, when I customize the theme and save draft, the error was appeared.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw85o.png)
This is the error message.

And I'm using this pro theme.
https://blossomthemes.com/wordpress-themes/blossom-feminine-pro/

- When I use the free theme, I didn't meet above error.
- I've uninstalled the pro theme and reinstalled, but it was still appeared.
- I've updated new wordpress version before installing the pro theme.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have a look at [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to learn how to read the error log, then share that information with us so we can help. That screenshot alone isn't really enough for anyone here to know what the problem is.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also try reaching out to the developers of the theme and [report the problem](https://blossomthemes.com/support-ticket/) so they can assist you with this.